# How to detect if IE 'scripted windows' security setting is enabled/disabled

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer

In IE's security settings there is a 'scripting' setting "Allow websites to prompt for information using scripted windows".

I'm attempting to use the "confim()" dialog as a simple confirmation for large db updates (before they're sent).  But the same applies when debugging for the appearance (or lack thereof) of alert().

If the security setting is set to disabled, the confirm just fails (same as if the user selected 'cancel').

I'd like to know if there is a way to programatically determine if the setting is disabled (before the actual confirm() call) and simply do the commit in that situation.  The confirmation is really only a nicety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did 'kind' of come up with a way to determine if a window.prompt() wasn't getting displayed by way of measuring the time it takes for the call to return. if it's less than 100ms then the user likely never saw it (ie it's disabled).

> 100ms == (an arbitrary number based on the 10th of a second rule : ie
>   the time the average human takes to react to a user interface under
>   optimal circumstances)

```
var start = (new Date).getTime();
var data = prompt("test","test");
var diff = (new Date).getTime() - start;
if( diff < 100 )
{
 // no prompt
}
else
{
 // prompt was displayed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The setting in question applies to the `window.prompt()` method and does not impact the `window.confirm()` method.

There's no way to detect the state of that setting from JavaScript without actually calling the method.

Comment: yes. you are correct. I think i'm getting some strange win8+IE10 behaviour. Every so often, IE refuses to display the confirm box. After a browser restart, it works again. Not sure why this is happening but I initially interpreted it to be a security setting issue.